# 1895-1904/com.android.mms E/StrictMode﹕ is this my Bug?

Tags: android

Any help given at this stage will be appreciated, i have tried reading but now i am actually confused, The first time it was Calender i went and introduced an exception and that has gone away now i see it is `mms` How can i deal with this? any advice?

```
 1895-1904/com.android.mms E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'release' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.drm.DrmManagerClient.<init>(DrmManagerClient.java:258)
            at com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduPersister.<init>(PduPersister.java:288)
            at com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduPersister.getPduPersister(PduPersister.java:299)
            at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService.onNewIntent(TransactionService.java:231)
            at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(TransactionService.java:633)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)



 1989-2046/com.android.email E/EmailServiceProxy﹕ RuntimeException when trying to unbind from service
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@1d27587c
            at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1029)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1808)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:551)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection$1.doInBackground(ServiceProxy.java:124)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection$1.doInBackground(ServiceProxy.java:111)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building a custom ROM and are modifying the `com.android.mms` and `com.android.email` apps, then perhaps these are your issues.

Otherwise, they are issues for the developers of the `com.android.mms` and `com.android.email` apps.

Comment: No i am not building a custom ROM neither am i modifying. Thanks.